# Adding a library to Composer in Symfony 2.1+

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I'm trying to add some libraries to `composer.json`

The libraries are located at `Symfony/vendor/foo/lib/Foo/*`

Before I loaded them under the `registerNamespaces` method in `autoload.php` as:

```
...
'Foo' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/foo/lib',
...
```

I have tried adding them as `"foo": "*"` and `"foo/foo": "*"` in composer.json to no avail. The documentation seems extremely lacking in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

You have to look at [Composers documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/), because the autoloading is completely taken over there. A good start to update ones Symfony 2.0 application I've used is to compare it against the current [Symfony Standard](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard). For your problem you should have a look at [app/autoload.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/17a0f1696192990017d02e461ebff4e475dfce37/app/autoload.php). There you can find

```
$loader = @include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'
```

in line 5 (within an `if`-expression, but thats not important here). This means, that as long as you let composer install the packages you don't have to take about the autoloading anymore. Of course you must call `php composer.phar install` first. If you don't know the name of the package, have a look at the packages `composer.json`-file, or search for it at [Packagist](http://packagist.org/)

Comment: If I want to install a bundle "manually" without composer. where I define namespaces?

Comment: @smoreno I would advise sticking with composer, don't mix and match